Aurora PostgreSQL writer spikes suddenly with high io:xactsync
It's been 3 weeks since this happened and it keeps happening every 3-4 days. We are using AWS RDS Aurora PostgreSQL and we have 6 DMS tasks to replicate the data from the RDS to S3, we have another dms task in another AWS account that migrates the data into our RDS. The writer instance is db.r6g.xlarge. We face sudden high CPU, io:xactsync, IO:ReorderBufferRead and IO:ReorderBufferWrite coming from the replication slots. The replication slots don't have any huge DML Operations at the moment of the spikes. I'll share cloud watch metrics in a 5 hour view interval. What should I look into to solve the issue?
CPU & Disk queue depth
Sessions & Network
IO
DB LOAD Graph
Top SQL
When I stop all the DMS tasks in our Account the issue fades away, when I try to Resume any DMS task it returns back for 30-45 minutes and then fades away. Even when I upgraded the Writer instance size to 2XLARGE it still happened.

We are also facing same issue and our support ticket is pending aws

@SurajSinghRathore It's fixed now. I checked the running transactions every time the incident happened, and I found out that there is a table coming from the DMS task receive bulk updates (millions of rows) so I stopped the replication of this table and since then the RDS is running fine.

in our case, AWS fixed something on their side to resolve this issue.
Response from AWS "I am glad to inform that our internal team had applied the mitigation to stop the cluster from having failovers. Please monitor and let us know if you see any further issues."
